# can't extend secondary partition in Windows - install of linux went to primary

Tags: grub2, bash, partitioning

I booted my Windows from grub and Ubuntu was made my primary, I'm pretty sure I installed in the one that isn't legacy, the other bios, boot. I did change a few setting in bios like boot order and stuff but actually wrote down the instructions.

So Windows is the secondary drive now and I cant resize the partition. It won't extend. I have windows 10 it came with the computer and have a cd of windows 7 but no disk drive.

When I booted the bash grub popped up and had to hit <kbd>f12</kbd> to boot into my windows secondary partition. only have 37GB hard drive, 16MG free, originally a 225 solid state. Just bought the computer.

How can I get Windows back to primary?

It says it's the primary but it's to the right and the Ubuntu partition is in front. I am not sure how do look up if its sda or sda1, but I'm guessing sda.

Is there a way to look it up in powershell? I'm so new to the commands and not having the best time right now.

Comment: Windows 10 is preinstalled using gpt not mbr. This means all partitions are primary. It is not clear if you have two physical hard drives. Please edit your question and provide details like partition names and drive identifiers. For example the first drive may be `/dev/sda`. The second drive may be `/dev/sdb`. The first partition in the first drive is `/dev/sda1`, second partition `/dev/sda2` etc.

Comment: @thomas Just in case anyone sees your comment without context, the context is here in the edit history: [Revision 2](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1052261/2)

Comment: can I attach a picture? im pretty sure its /dev/sda, it's primary but it is too the right and unbuntu is first on the partion, hmessed up the computer pretty bad. only have 16mb free and can't doing anything useful too pass the time

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo parted -l`? Thanks.